# Coating the internal wall and the nanoparticles in 3D porous structure

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm a Blender newbie.
I want to coat the internal wall of the 3D porous structure (attached) with another material.

I would appreciate your feedback.

Thanks.

[image: 3D porous structure]

[image: Geometry node]

[image: 2D structure]

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is the problem... you already have _Set Material_ nodes in different parts of the setup, you already figured out how to give the nano particles a different material than the walls. What do you need now? Find out how to color the walls? Figure out how to get "controlled opacity" (whatever "controlled" means in this case)?

Comment: Hi Gordon.
Thanks for responding. 
I want to coat the internal wall of this porous structure with another material. Conceptually, imagine another material impregnating through the pores and creating a connected network. I attached a 2D illustration of what I am targeting in 3D.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I repaired your image links. Yeah I mean what I don't understand is why don't you simply add another _Set Material_ node with a material for the inner walls? Somewhere in the node setup there must be a place where these walls come from, and there you should place it. But I'm sorry that I'm not willing nor have the time to search through all these nodes and try to understand the geometry or maybe even recreate it manually on my computer to find the correct place.

Comment: This question might be a real clunk, sorry if so... Is this a one-off model, or do you need to be able to create variations, procedurally? If one-off, why are you using Geometry Nodes?

Comment: Yes, it is a one-off model. I have little knowledge about the alternatives. Based on all of the suggestions I've received so far and the tutorials I've seen on YouTube, the G node appeared to be the best bet.